# How to inject same dependency object for both a web host and a hosted service in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to use dependency injection to inject the same instance of an object into a web host and a hosted service. Is there a way to do this? Or is there some workaround that yields the same result?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.Services.AddLogging();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ExampleService>(); // Orchestrator is available in ExampleService

                services.AddSingleton<Orchestrator>();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); // Orchestrator not available in "Startup"
            });
}
```

Someone describes [the problem in more detail here](https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/) but doesn't provide a solution that would work in this scenario.

Comment: A hosted service gets the same DI graph that any other service in ASP.Net gets, such as controllers. If you're using `UseStartup`, there is no need to have a seperate _ConfigureServices_. Put all that logic in Startup.

Comment: Thanks, that seems so obvious now that you mention it. This is the solution I decided to go for and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dependency injection for the startup class. The reason for this is that the startup class is actually created *before* the service container is being build. If you consider what one of the two primary purposes of the startup class is, then it makes sense too: The `Startup.ConfigureService` method is used to configure the service container. Similarly to how you register the hosted service using the `ConfigureServices` method on the host builder, you can also configure it within the startup’s `ConfigureServices` method and it will have the same effect. Because both methods are configuring the same service container.

For that reason, it’s conceptually not possible that the `Startup` class could be created (and as such receive dependencies from the service container) when it is actually used to configure the service container before its creation.

If you need your `Orchestrator` service in your startup class, then you are likely doing something suboptimal: If you need to configure the service container using this orchestrator, consider using something like a factory instead, or configure things at runtime. Otherwise, if you need your orchestrator to affect the application pipeline, then you can just inject the type directly into the `Configure` method of your startup.

Finally, note the difference in your question title: *“inject same dependency object for both a web host and a hosted service”*. You **are** able to inject the dependency in both the hosted service and the *web host*. But the startup class is *not* the web host, it just configures the web host.